# Firebase throwing FirebaseException instead of FirebaseNetworkException when there's no internet

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Per [Firebase Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/FirebaseNetworkException), a FirebaseNetworkException should be thrown if there are network connectivity problems when logging in. However, when I place the device in Airplane Mode and attempt to login, a FirebaseException gets thrown with this detailMessage

> "An internal error has occurred. [ 7: ]"

Ideally a FirebaseNetworkException would be thrown so that the app has enough context to let the user know the exact problem.

Would matching on this detailMessage (i.e 'if you get this exception with this detailMessage, tell the user to check internet connectivity') be safe?

Comment: If you think you've found a bug, please [file a bug report](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) with Firebase support (since the Android SDK for Auth isn't open sourced yet). There's nothing anyone here can do about that.

Comment: Are you sure the exception is a basic `FirebaseException` and not a [`FirebaseAuthException`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuthException.html). The latter has an error code, which you can safely handle in your code.